# Example of self-dual hypergraph with infinite edges

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

What is an example of a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) $H=(V,E)$ with $|e|\geq \aleph_0$ for all $e\in E$ and the property that $H\cong H^*$ where $H^*$ is the [dual hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph#Terminology) of $H$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V = \mathbb R$ and $E = \{(-\infty,r] : r \in \mathbb R\}$.